# Recurrence. Nonhomogeneous recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the following recurrence relation:
$$ {a_{n+1}}={(a_{n})}^2-2 ,\\a_0=\frac{5}{2}$$ 
 Prove that $\left \lfloor{a_{n}}\right \rfloor $ is a power of 2 for every natural number *n*, using recurrence equation transformations ( i.e. without induction).

Comment: I tried using the transformation of the equation, but can't arrive to an explicit formula:
$$ {a_{n+1}+1}={(a_{n}-1)}{(a_n+1)} $$
$$ b_n = a_n+1 $$
$$ {b_{n+1}}={(b_{n}-2)}{(b_n)} $$
$$ {b_{n+1}}={(b_{n})^2-2b_n} $$

Comment: $a_{n}=2^{n+1}+\dfrac1{2^{n+1}}$

Comment: I keep getting $$a_n = 2^{2^{n}} + \left(2^{2^n}\right)^{-1}$$ but all answers say otherwise. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @peterwhy that's because you are correct and the question is a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use the Ansatz that $\,a_n = b_n + b_n^{-1}\,$ which implies
$\, a_n^2 = b_n^2 + b_n^{-2} + 2\,$ and hence
$\,a_n^2 - 2 = b_n^2 + b_n^{-2}.\,$ Using the $\,a\,$ recurrence $\,a_{n+1} = a_n^2-2,\,$ we get that
$\,b_{n+1} = b_n^2\,$ with $\,b_0 = 2^1.\,$ Solving this $\,b\,$ recurrence and, using the inequality
$\,0 < b_n^{-1} < 1,\,$ we find that $\,b_n = 2^{2^n} = \lfloor a_n \rfloor.\,$ As a comment to the question notes, this is essentially a duplicate question.

Comment: As per the comments, the answer is not entirely accurate ... although it's easy to fix it.

Comment: @rtybase Oops! Of, course. I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use induction to show that
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n= \frac{2^{2(n+1)}+1}{{2^{n+1}}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I am supposed to find a solution by only manipulating the recurrence equations, I missed that part.